# Use jquery to keep summing numbers of a class element

Tags: jquery, sum

I cannot get the sum to work here..

```
<button id="button">Add 20</button>
<div class="number"></div>

var n = 0;
var str = "one:40";
var substr = str.split(":");

alert(substr[1]);

$('#button').live('click', function() {
   $('.number').append($('<p />', {text: n += substr[1]}));     
});
```

I'm getting the output as:

```
040
04040
0404040
040404040
```

I want to add the number to class='number'. Here is the jsfiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/SXF8H/123/

Comment: are you trying to parse string to number?  $('.number').append($('<p />', {text: n += parseInt(substr[1])}));  Hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to convert the string into int as

```
var n = 0;
var str = "one:40";
var substr = str.split(":");
alert(substr[1]);

$('#button').live('click', function() {
    $('.number').append($('<p />', {text: n += parseInt(substr['1'])}));     
});
```